# Xamarin forms check if user is currently logged

Tags: android, database, xamarin.forms

I need to create login validations so that only one user can log into a given account at a time.

I found that the best solution would be to log the login event to the database and delete the data row after the user logs in.

Everything seems easy to do, but I have one case that I cannot solve.

When a user's device shuts down or is unloaded, there will still be an entry in the database that the user is logged in and will block logging in to that account.

I thought about making a date field in DB that would be updated and checked every few minutes, if that time differs by e.g. 2 minutes from the current time.

But I am afraid that this would cause too many queries to DB and slow down my application

Can you suggest any solution to this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the [Preferences API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=ios) from [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/) to store current user's refresh token (or any other user identifier).

According to Essentials' documentation:

> Uninstalling the application will cause all *Preferences* to be removed, with the exception being apps that target and run on Android 6.0 (API level 23) or later that use Auto Backup. This feature is on by default and preserves app data including Shared Preferences, which is what the Preferences API utilizes. You can disable this by following Google's documentation.

```cs
using Xamarin.Essentials;

public class CredentialsStore
{
    private const string _currentUserTokenKey = "CurrentUserToken";

    // set the current user's refresh token
    public void SetCurrentUserToken(string token)
    {
        Preferences.Set(_currentUserTokenKey, token);
    }

    // retreive the current user's refresh token
    public string GetCurrentUserToken()
    {
        return Preferences.Get(_currentUserTokenKey, null);
    }

    // check if a user is loggen in
    public bool IsUserLoggedIn()
    {
        var token = GetCurrentUserToken();
        return token != null;
    }

    // logout
    public void ClearCurrentUserToken()
    {
        Preferences.Remove(_currentUserTokenKey);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
CredentialsStore credentialsStore;

//login
var newUserToken = "123456789";
credentialsStore.SetCurrentUserToken(newUserToken);

//check if user loggen in
if(credentialsStore.IsUserLoggedIn())
{
    //retreive user info
    var token = credentialsStore.GetCurrentUserToken();

    //use user info 
    await apiService.DoSomethingAsync(token);
}

//logout
credentialsStore.ClearCurrentUserToken();
```

Does this help?